# Making a data URI from unicode string

Tags: javascript, unicode, data-uri

I'm trying to make JavaScript download a unicode string as a text file. I'm at the point where I need to convert the unicode string into a data URL, so that the user can open the URL and download the file.
Here is a simplification of my code:

```
var myString = "⌀怴ꁴ㥍䯖챻巏ܛ肜怄셀겗孉贜짥孍ಽ펾曍㩜䝺捄칡⡴얳锭劽嫍ᯕ�";

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64,' + myString);
```

I don't know what character set to use or how to encode my string - I've tried combinations of `encodeURI()` and `btoa()`, but haven't managed to get anything working. `encodeURI()` gives me the error `Uncaught URI Error: malformed URI` for some characters like `U+da7b`.
I would prefer the final downloaded file to have the same characters as the initial string.

Comment: You'll have to use a `try`/`catch` block to isolate failures.

Comment: Note that the only "correct" way to do this is to use a [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem) to make sure `btoa` gets clean input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is working for me

```
decodeURIComponent(atob(btoa(encodeURIComponent("中文"))))
// Output: 中文
```

And for your case on `\uDA7B`, it fails because it's one of the high surrogates (D800-DBFF), it is meaningful only when used as part of a surrogate pair.

That's why you have the URIError when you do

`encodeURIComponent('\uDA7B') // ERROR`

Pair it with a character from the low surrogates (DC00-DFFF) and it works:

`encodeURIComponent('\uDA7B\uDC01')`

Comment: You don't need to url-encode the text before base64-encoding it. But you do need to make sure the text is charset-encoded first, such as to UTF-8, and then you can specify that charset in the `data:` url.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how to make a text charset-encoded? I always use `encodeURIComponent` bcz it's the easiest way to convert anything to Latin1 charset

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` charset-encodes the text to UTF-8 and then url-encodes the UTF-8 bytes.  For a `data:` URL, the url-encoding is not needed when using base64.

Comment: so if I want charset-encode only I should try something like the new Encoder API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder

Comment: You could use that to get an array of UTF-8 bytes, yes.  But, to base64 that afterwards, you would have to copy the bytes into  a `string` since `btoa()` doesn't take a byte array as input.

Comment: thanks ;) I didn't know that api is available until today

Comment: Note that you don't control the decoding of a data-url, so this isn't super helpful: yes, decodeURIComponent is the counterpart to encodeURIComponent, but you don't always _get_ the content decoded as URI component, e.g. when passing a data-url into a `<script>` src attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use base64 when using text in a [`data:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), simply percent-encoding the text will suffice, eg:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(myString));
```

`encodeURIComponent()` charset-encodes the text to UTF-8, and then url-encodes the UTF-8 bytes, hence the inclusion of `charset=UTF-8` in the `data:` URL.

But, if you still want to use base64, you don't need to url-encode the text.  Just charset-encode the text to bytes, then base64-encode the bytes, and specify the charset used in the `data:` URL, eg:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(myString))));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the download attribute and using [URL encoding with text/plain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

```js
const myString = '⌀怴ꁴ㥍䯖챻巏ܛ肜怄셀겗孉贜짥孍ಽ펾曍㩜䝺捄칡⡴얳锭劽嫍ᯕ�';

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('download', 'filename');
link.append("Download!");
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:,' + encodeURI(myString));

document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, some characters like `U+DA7B` (stackoverflow won't let me upload the actual character) give me the error: `Uncaught URI Error: malformed URI`.

Comment: `encodeURI()` expects a whole URI as input, but `myString` is not a URI.  Try using `encodeURIComponent()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is called out as [the "Unicode Problem"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem) in the Base 64 documentation on MDN, with the solution using a [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder):

```js
function base64ToBytes(base64) {
  const binString = atob(base64);
  return Uint8Array.from(binString, (m) => m.codePointAt(0));
}

function bytesToBase64(bytes) {
  const binString = String.fromCodePoint(...bytes);
  return btoa(binString);
}

const encoded = bytesToBase64(new TextEncoder().encode("a Ā  文 "));
console.log(`encoded:`, encoded);

const decoded = new TextDecoder().decode(base64ToBytes("YSDEgCDwkICAIOaWhyDwn6aE"));
console.log(`decoded:`, decoded);
```

Unlike solutions involving `encodeURIComponent`, which don't work when the data-url is used in something that does not apply URI decoding, such as `<script>` src attributes, this approach will work for everything:

```js
// use the above approach for string input
function base64(string) {
  const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(string);
  const binString = String.fromCodePoint(...bytes);
  return btoa(binString);
}

// declare a unicorn:
const unicorn = ``;

// dynamically generate a new javascript module that exports
// a function called test() that console logs our unicorn:
const customScript = `
  export function test() {
    console.log("${unicorn}");
  }
`;

console.log(`script is:`, customScript);

// turn this script into a data URL using TextEncoder and btoa:
const dataURL = `data:text/javascript;base64,${base64(customScript)}`

// then import that module by turning it into a data-url,
// which should console log our unicorn emoji:
import(dataURL)
  .then((lib) => lib.test())
  .catch(e => console.log(`loading failed: ${e.message}`));
```

If we try to do this with `encodeURIComponent`, the browser will grind to a halt:

```js
// dynamically generate a new javascript module
const unicorn = ``;
const customScript = `
  export function test() {
    console.log("${unicorn}");
  }
`;

console.log(`script is:`, customScript);

// turn this script into a data URL with encodeURICompoennt:
const dataURL = `data:text/javascript;base64,${btoa(encodeURIComponent(customScript))}`;

// then import that as new JS module, which will fail.
import(dataURL)
  .then((lib) => lib.test())
  .catch(e => console.log(`loading failed: ${e.message}`));
```

(With the universal caveat that if the server's CSP is set to disallow `data:`, this won't do anything. But when it *is* permitted, the correct way to get text with Unicode data turned into a base64 data URL is by using TextEncoder)